# yii2 composer update on windows machine with cmd getting error

Tags: yii2

i having the problem with updating extinctions through composer on local windows 7 machine.

i just want to add

```
"kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev"
```

in composer.json file.

after adding this line of code and giving command to update on cmd as..

```
composer update
```

its showing me following error message on cmd line.. please see this one..
[image]

i just change code in composer `"minimum-stability": "stable",`

to `"minimum-stability": "dev",

as i got solution from stackoverflow so i tried but not work for me.

my whole composer code is here..

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

}

please help... it will be a great appreciation for me.

Thanking you in advanced.

Comment: it really just says what is missing: you are missing bower-asset/jquery-inputmask.

Here are a few commands i run:
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install

maybe also run a bower command -> http://bower.io/docs/api/

Comment: yes... i already tye for composer self-update and composer update but not working.. same issue.. i dont know why it is happen..?

Comment: Just read the error log: it is missing missing bower-asset/jquery-inputmask file. I bet when you got that in your folder it is good to go

Comment: yeah.. its missing.. so now what to do...?

Comment: If you use bower aswell use command:
bower install jquery.inputmask
and 
bower install jquery

i bet you will go a long way with that.

Comment: And yes...the real problem you have no composer asset plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cmd

```
php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
 php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"
```

Then run your command

Comment: You should check before, there is a newer version of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the following command first:

`composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"`

Comment: You should check before, there is a newer version of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
composer selfupdate
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way to install last version.

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1"
```